# Using SelectMany Extension Method to Select Multiple Columns from DataRow List with result as subset of datarow list

Tags: c#, extension-methods, linq-to-objects

I have a datatable containing 10 columns. I want to select only two columns of them.

I am not able to do it using `SelectMany` Extension Method.

I know how to get it from Linq To DataSet but trying using this extension method.

Comment: To All: i got it working after your help. But I was expecting result to be of type List<DataRow> but it gives me result of type whose parameter i passes any solution to get DataRow Back as a result.`var distinctItems=itemListToCreate.Select(dr=>new {ItemId=dr.Field<long>("FK_ITEM_ID"),SessionId= dr.Field<long>("FK_SESSION_ID")});`

Comment: Dear,
Can you tell me how to achieve this in linq, i have a table with two columns (ID & Name) and some 20 rows in it, each time i need to select only 2 or 3 rows only by ID and output should be only the selected rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method is used for flattening a sequence of sequences, not for just selecting a subset of the available columns. Use the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method instead:

```
var query = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(r => new { Column3 = r[3], Column6 = r[6] });
```

Answer (score 3):

`SelectMany` is the wrong method to try to use. You simply need to use `Select` and create a new anonymous object:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { r.Column1, r.Column7 });
```

`SelectMany` is used to flatten nested collections.

Answer (score 0):

var s = table.Rows.Cast().Select(....);